# Back button text prob with iOS 8

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios8

Following is the code which used for back button text

```
UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101]; // left-pointing shape!           
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setTitle:parent.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if (backButton.frame.size.width >= 140.0f)
            {
                [backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 140.0f, 30.0f)];
            }
backNaviButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

Above code working fine with iOS 7 and below versions

Here are the compare screen shots

iOS 7

[image]

iOS 8
[image]

Comment: Hmm... that first line of code looks suspicious. You'd probably be better creating a `UIBarButton` with system type `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone` (left pointy shape, as you call it). Then add an action to it.

Comment: why not try checking the text length and then displaying a substring with desired range if it is over a certain character length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test against string length rather than button width

```
UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101]; // left-pointing shape!           
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if (parent.title.length>maxStringLength) {

    [backButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",[parent.title substringToIndex:maxStringLength]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [backButton setTitle:parent.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: It works fine,but the thing is that is cut down the rest text and user will feel that button has this much text it is not showing ... if the name is big